# Return rows with highest key value matching particular condition

Tags: sql-server

We have a routine which synchronises data from a client database into our own DB.

The routine must pick out the record with the highest RecordID for each ItemID and Year.

The desired result is that for each query, the most recent item for ItemID 1 in 2014, ItemID 1 in 2015, ItemID 1 in 2016 are returned, with this pattern repeated for each item ID and year in the raw data.

In cases where there are multiple records for a given year, the record with the highest unique id must be returned for each year and grouped by an item identifier.

The RecordID is an auto incrementing primary key where the highest value is the most recently created.

The pseudocode select is:

```
select record with the highest RecordID for each ItemID and Year

RecordID | ItemID | Year
1        | 1      | 2014
2        | 1      | 2014
3        | 2      | 2014
4        | 2      | 2015
5        | 2      | 2015
6        | 2      | 2016
```

In the example data, what should be returned is

```
RecordID | ItemID | Year
2        | 1      | 2014
3        | 2      | 2014
5        | 2      | 2015
6        | 2      | 2016
```

In the present form, we load the entire dataset into a datatable (c#), and for each item ID, get the list of matching years, then take the highest record ID which matches that item ID and year.

The closest I have managed to get with straight SQL is:

```
select max(recordId), itemId, Year 
from Records 
group by recordId, ItemId, year 
order by itemId desc, year desc, recordId desc
```

This however returns all the records listed, and although it correctly orders them with the most recent at the top of each group, it does not bring back only the most recent.

I know there must be a solution in straight SQL for this, but I'm really struggling to see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The example shown is a replica of the structure in our source DB, but I'm unable to post the exact structure as there are a vast number of columns containing client data which cannot be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try the window functions.

```
Select *
 From (
        Select *,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By ItemID,Year Order By RecordId Desc)
        From   YourTable
      ) A
 Where RowNr=1
```

Comment: If I leave the `RowNr` restriction in place, this returns only the most recent item for the most recent year. What I need is the most recent item for every year where there is a record for that item. When I remove the retriction, it returns all rows, rather than one for each year.

Comment: @Alex Misunderstood the question ... Add Year to the Partition By

Comment: That's almost excatly what I need, although it's returning the lowest record ID per year rather than the highest

Comment: @Alex, are you sure you're ordering by recordID Desc?  It defaults to Asc, if you forget the Desc part.

Comment: @Beth - yup, it's definately ordering descending.

Comment: @Alex, what do the results from the inner select look like?

Comment: My appologies, I was ordering by itemId not record ID. This is now returning exactly what I need. Thanks @JohnCappelletti, you've just saved me a vast amount of stress!!!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, in fairness, it was you who gave me the select and Beth who prompted me to check the ordering. I wouldn't have spotted it otherwise!!!

Answer (score 2):

you should not have recordid in group by

```
select max(recordId), itemId, Year 
from Records 
group by ItemId, year 
order by itemId desc, year desc
```

Comment: When I remove the equivelant column for recordid in my query on the live data, I get an error stating that the column `is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`. I was trying variations on this last night, but kept running into the same issue.

Comment: you need to add order by itemId desc, year desc, max(recordid) desc

Comment: Columns in aggregation cannot be used directly in order by

Comment: Thank you! That's pretty much exactly what I was after. There are a number of other columns I need to return as well, but I can always take the record IDs and use them in an inner select to pull those back.

Comment: This answer got me pretty close to a solution, but as I would have needed an outer select to pull back the rest of the data to synchronise (or a second datatable which I filter from the results), I've gone with the partitioning approach.